# How to fetch inverse ticker data in Pine Editor

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I need to be able to fetch the data from the inverse ticker i'm currently working on in the script.

I used the following code in the script so that i am able to work on the data from this inverse ticker:
inverseticker = '0 - syminfo.ticker'

it gets validated when saving the script, but when i load it, it displays "Study Error - invalid symbol: 0 - syminfo.ticker".

I know 0-AAPL, or 0-TSLA works when you call them from Tradingview itself, but i'm unable to code it.

Anyone would know how to do?

Thank you

I tried what i said and it did not work.
I'm expecting a solution